# Find file , create subdirectory and move

Tags: bash

I have the follow  Direcory tree.

```
Comb
|
|--- 1.json2
|--- 1.cc.json2.ml
|--- 102.cc.json2.pre2.ml
|--- 1.json2.pre1
|--- 102.json2.pre1
```

I need   create and bash to make  this result.

```
Comb
|--|
   |-1
   |  |--- 1.json2
   |  |--- 1.cc.json2.ml
   |  |--- 1.json2.pre1
   |- 102
       |--- 102.cc.json2.pre2.ml    
       |--- 102.json2.pre1
```

I tryed some like this but  in some point this break  and lost files.

```
for file in *.cc.json2.pre2.ml; do mkdir -- "${file%.cc.json2.pre2.ml}"; mv -- "$file" "${file%.cc.json2.pre2.ml}"; done

for file in *.cc.json2.pre1.ml; do mkdir -- "${file%.cc.json2.pre1.ml}"; mv -- "$file" "${file%.cc.json2.pre1.ml}"; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shellscript should work for the directory tree that you show in your question.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.*
do
 if test -e "$i"
 then
  tmp="${i%%.*}"
  mkdir -p "$tmp"
  mv -i "$i" "$tmp"
 else
  echo "No file or directory matching '$i'"
 fi
done
```

- 'Change directory', `cd`,  into the directory.
- Create the shellscript.
- Give it a name *without any dot*, for example `shellscript` (because you don't want it to move itself),
- Run the shellscript with

  ```
  bash shellscript
  ```
- If you intend to create new files at the top of the directory tree and run the shellscript again, you may wish to 'make it executable',

  ```
  chmod +x shellscript
  ```

  Then you can run it 'directly',

  ```
  ./shellscript
  ```

Comment: This work very well thx!

Comment: @Jess, You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may simplify this using `glob` patterns. If you are in the `Comb` directory then you can do something like this.

```
mkdir 1 102
mv 1\.* 1/
mv 102\.* 102/
```

No loops are needed for this simple task, but if you have files of the same form like
`3.somefile.ml` `103.mm.ml` `66.anotherfile.json` you can do better by automating this

```
names=(`ls -1 | grep -Po "^\d+" | uniq `)
mkdir ${names}
for i in ${names[@]}
do
 mv $i\.* $i        
done
```

This uses `glob` pattern as well and creates a folder for each unique numbered files.

Comment: thx for the explanation! great work!

Answer (score 1):

```
cd Comb
for i in *; do mkdir -p ${i%%.*txt}; mv $i ${i%%.*txt}; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You weren't too far off with your attempts. Try this small adaption of your own code:

```
$ for file in *.cc.json*ml; do mkdir -p ${file%%.*}; mv -v ${file%%.*}.* ${file%%.*}; done
renamed '102.cc.json2.pre2.ml' -> '102/102.cc.json2.pre2.ml'
renamed '102.json2.pre1' -> '102/102.json2.pre1'
renamed '1.cc.json2.ml' -> '1/1.cc.json2.ml'
renamed '1.json2' -> '1/1.json2'
renamed '1.json2.pre1' -> '1/1.json2.pre1'
```